# Efficiency of queries against DATABASE Issue

Tags: php, mysql, join

I`m trying to query my database with 4 queries, each query will give me the number of rows that I need but I faced with but I notice when I do the query on the server that strong, everything works fast (relatively), but if I make it a relatively simple server that I deserve the maximum working time (30 seconds, the limit execution time(PHP)).
my while loop works with list of MokedCcode each MokedCcode goes into the queries and go to the next MokedCcode.
**Notes :** 
1) I know it will be proportional to the number of MokedCcode-s.
2) I need to increase the execution time limit?

1) there is more efficient way to make those queries? maybe I dont use the mysql features right.
for example the first query called $emerg, this query need to give me the number of rows between dates, where WCODE have priority 1 and it has to be match of MokedCcode on both tables ( t and e ).

```
$emerg = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT  t.*,e.DISCODE,e.AREA,e.COLOR,e.PRIORITY FROM    $tbl_name AS t   
 LEFT JOIN eventcodes AS e ON t.MokedCcode = e.MokedCcode AND t.WCODE=e.WCODE  
 WHERE (t.MokedCcode='$MokedCcode' ) AND e.PRIORITY='1' 
 AND t.ndate BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' ORDER By `id` DESC "));
```

In addition I added the 3 more queries, I would like to get some advice how to make it faster Or I dont have any choice and keep it like that.

**The 3 other queries:**

```
    $regular = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT  t.*,e.DISCODE,e.AREA,e.COLOR,e.PRIORITY FROM $tbl_name AS t    
    LEFT JOIN eventcodes AS e ON t.MokedCcode = e.MokedCcode AND t.WCODE=e.WCODE  
    WHERE (t.MokedCcode='$MokedCcode' ) AND e.PRIORITY!='1' 
    AND t.ndate BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' ORDER By `id` DESC "));

    $regHandled = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT  t.*,e.DISCODE,e.AREA,e.COLOR,e.PRIORITY FROM $tbl_name AS t  
    LEFT JOIN eventcodes AS e ON t.MokedCcode = e.MokedCcode AND t.WCODE=e.WCODE 
    WHERE (t.MokedCcode='$MokedCcode' ) AND e.PRIORITY!='1' 
    AND t.EventHandling!='0' AND t.ndate BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' ORDER By `id` DESC "));

    $emergHandled = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT  t.*,e.DISCODE,e.AREA,e.COLOR,e.PRIORITY FROM $tbl_name AS t  
    LEFT JOIN eventcodes AS e ON t.MokedCcode = e.MokedCcode AND t.WCODE=e.WCODE  
    WHERE (t.MokedCcode='$MokedCcode' ) AND e.PRIORITY='1'
    AND t.EventHandling!='0' AND t.ndate BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' ORDER By `id` DESC "));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve.

If you just want the count Why are you selecting all the rows? cant you use `COUNT()` MySQL function? It is always slow to get all the data to your script and then count the rows.

Even if you want to select all those columns, try using `t.field1, t.field2, ...` instead of `t.*`

Comment: COUNT will decrease the work time? And why I need to choose the specific cols?

Comment: Your issue concerns efficiency. The respondent has suggested ways in which you might make your code more efficient.

Comment: @OfirAttia COUNT() means you count the rows at the server and get the result which is basically an integer. You don't have to fetch all the data (which can be bulky) to your script and count. When you use t.*, the server first needs to determine the fields to fetch then do the actual fetch where when you specify the field names the first overhead is not there.